# How to enable SMTP server in Windows Server 2012

Tags: command-line-interface, powershell, windows-server-2012

We are using servermanager.exe to install smtp server in windows 2008R2 from comand prompt.
Is there any alternate to servermanager.exe?
How to enable smtp server in windows 2012 from command prompt?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, checking, adding and removing Windows components like this from the command line can be done via the powershell commands [get-WindowsFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662312.aspx), [install-WindowsFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662309.aspx), and to remove the feature afterwards [remove-WindowsFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662310.aspx).

To see if SMTP server is installed already use

```
get-WindowsFeature smtp-server
```

To install it use

```
install-WindowsFeature smtp-server
```

If you want a bit of re-usable code you can use everywhere to check if the SMTP server is already installed, and if not then install it then something like this ought to do it

```
smtp = get-WindowsFeature smtp-server
 if (!smtp.Installed) {
  $smtp | add-WindowsFeature
  }
```