# PowerShell Script for enable smtp

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I started to play around with Windows Server.

In PowerShell the command `DISM /online /Enable-Feature /Featurename:NetFx3 /All` will  install .NET Framework 3.5 by using DISM. [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-manager/install-or-uninstall-roles-role-services-or-features).

I need a similar command that installs SMTP featue, do you know how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable SMTP server in Windows Server 2012](https://serverfault.com/questions/474781/how-to-enable-smtp-server-in-windows-server-2012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice [answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/474781/how-to-enable-smtp-server-in-windows-server-2012) by [Rob](https://serverfault.com/users/7783/rob-moir)

> To see if SMTP server is installed already use
>
> get-WindowsFeature smtp-server
>
> To install it use
>
> install-WindowsFeature smtp-server